# ListView selector does not work when views inside listitem are clickable

Tags: listview

I have a listview where views(ImageView and TextView) inside listitem are clickable. I have also set onClickListener on rowview inside adapter getView() to make whole row clickable. When I click on list item, I don't see any color change however it works on other listviews. I tried drawSelectorOnTop(True) in xml but still no color change. I also tried using following ListSelector with a different color in pressed state but no luck.

Can any please help me on this?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to change background. Rather using using selector on ListView, I used it on List Row View background in xml and it worked.